# mocha test sends `test` as variable to node app

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

When writing the tests for my entry file, `index.js` I run into the problem that the command `mocha test` passes `test` as an argument to `index.js` as it uses `process.argv` to receive parameters to run on a development environment. I had thought that by using something like `minimist` to name the parameters would fix this, however this problem still remains when running the tests. In this way my tests do not use the object provided in my test suits, as shown in the following code.

How do I get around this, so that when running my tests, it uses the `event` object I provide in my test set-up and not the command `mocha test`?

index.js

```
'use strict';


var _ = require("underscore");
var async = require('async');
var argv = require("minimist")(process.argv.slice(2));

var getprotocol = require("./getProtocol");
var _getprotocol = getprotocol.getProtocol;

var S3rs = require("./S3resizer");
var s3resizer = S3rs.rs;

var objCr = require("./objectCreator");
var createObj = objCr.creator;

var fileRs = require("./fileResizer");
var fileResizer = fileRs.rs;

var configs = require("./configs.json");

var mkDir = require("./makeDir");
var makeDir = mkDir.handler;



exports.imageRs = function (event, context) {

    var _path = argv.x || event.path; //argv.x used to be process.argv[2]

    console.log("Path, %s", _path);

    var _dir = argv.y; // used to be process.argv[3]

    console.log(_dir);

    var parts = _getprotocol(_path);

    var imgName = parts.pathname.split("/").pop();

    console.log("imgName: %s", imgName);

    var s3Bucket = parts.hostname;

    var s3Key = imgName;

    var _protocol = parts.protocol;

    console.log(_protocol);

    // RegExp to check for image type
    var imageTypeRegExp = /(?:(jpg)|(png)|(jpeg))$/;

    var sizesConfigs = configs.sizes;

    var obj = createObj(_path);

    // Check if file has a supported image extension
    var imgExt = imageTypeRegExp.exec(s3Key);

    if (imgExt === null) {
        console.error('unable to infer the image type for key %s', s3Key);
        context.done(new Error('unable to infer the image type for key %s' + s3Key));
        return;
    }

    var imageType = imgExt[1] || imgExt[2];
    // Do more stuff here
};

if (!process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT) {
    exports.imageRs();
}
```

test.js

```
describe("imgeRs", function () {

    var getprotocol = require("../getProtocol");
    var S3rs = require("../S3resizer");
    var objCr = require("../objectCreator");
    var mkDir = require("../makeDir");
    var fileResizer = require("../fileResizer");

    describe("Calling S3", function () {
        describe("Success call", function () {

            var testedModule, eventObj, contextDoneSpy, S3resizerStub, objCreatorStub, getProtocolStub, fakeResults, mkDirStub, fileResizerStub;

            before(function (done) {
                contextDoneSpy = sinon.spy();

                S3resizerStub = sinon.stub(S3rs, "rs");

                objCreatorStub = sinon.stub(objCr, 'creator');

                getProtocolStub = sinon.stub(getprotocol, "getProtocol");

                mkDirStub = sinon.stub(mkDir, "handler");

                fileResizerStub = sinon.stub(fileResizer, "rs");

                eventObj = {"path": "s3://theBucket/image.jpeg"};

                fakeResults = ["resized"];

                testedModule = proxyquire("../index", {
                    './getProtocol': {
                        'getProtocol': getProtocolStub
                    },
                    './S3resizer': {
                        'rs': S3resizerStub
                    },
                    './objectCreator': {
                        'creator': objCreatorStub
                    },
                    './makeDir': {
                        'handler': mkDirStub
                    },
                    './fileResizer': {
                        'rs': fileResizerStub
                    }
                });

                S3resizerStub.callsArgWith(5, null, fakeResults);

                testedModule.imageRs(eventObj, {done: function (error) {
                    contextDoneSpy.apply(null, arguments);
                    done();
                }});
            });

            after(function () {
                S3rs.rs.restore();
                objCr.creator.restore();
                getprotocol.getProtocol.restore();
                mkDir.handler.restore();
                fileResizer.rs.restore();
            });

            it("calls context.done with no error", function () {
                expect(contextDoneSpy).has.been.called;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you change imageRs to *always* use the 'event' object, and pass it  argv.x at the end of index.js ? Or inverse the condition ? (Use event.path if provided, and argv.x if no event is passed ?)

Comment: I have changed the condition to look like this: ` if (!event) {
        console.log("Using argv.x");
        _path = argv.x;
    } else {
        console.log("Using event");
        _path = event.path;
    }`

Comment: But the result is still the same. It still tries to use `argv.x`. And `console.log(event)` returns undefined before the condition.